# Only portrait orientation to a form on a FireMonkey Mobile Android application

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am developing a mobile app with Delphi XE5, Android platform.

I need one form in my mobile FireMonkey app to keep it's set orientation and not change when device is turned.  Other forms however can change orientation when device is turned.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please add the common `delphi` tag to all of your `delphi` related questions

Answer (score 0):

Delphi XE5 does not provide any setting on the form to do this, and one cannot make one form never rotate whilst others do.  You can perhaps create a work-around solution but a lot of testing would be required to ensure it works on all devices.  Probably not a good idea.

The FormPaint event is fired after the form repaints (when rotation is changed and other actions).  The form Height & Width will give you the current size and if you have a list of devices form sizes you could work out whether the form is currently in portrait / landscape mode.  You cannot force the form to another orientation, but you can hide controls and display a message.

Not easy and possibly not worth the effort.